# Artifactory stopped working randomly and now getting Unable to connect to http://localhost:8046

Tags: artifactory

At 10:09AM yesterday (July 19), my Artifactory instance stopped working. From the logs it looks like the health check (heartbeat) was failing and the ping check failed. Here's the first entry:

```
2023-07-19T17:09:02.402Z ^[[36m[jfrou]^[[0m ^[[31;1m[ERROR]^[[0m [61d965809180fd0 ] [local_topology.go:112         ] [main                ] - periodic send heartbeat failed for 4 consecutive times. Last error: failed sending heartbeat information to Access: failed closing Access grpc client: closing heartbeat client and waiting for response timed-out

2023-07-19T17:10:39.910Z ^[[1;32m[jfrt ]^[[0;39m ^[[1;31m[ERROR]^[[0;39m [6a3f49e4c58ecac8] [o.a.r.r.s.PingResource:90     ] [http-nio-8081-exec-5] - Error during ping test
org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientException: Access service is unavailable: Unable to connect to Access server: Read timed out
```

After restarting the service, I'm getting the  below error.

```
2023-07-19T17:38:05.316Z [jfmd ] [INFO ] [6748847a95daf67e] [accessclient.go:49            ] [main                ] - Cluster join: Retry 20: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping: dial tcp [::1]:8046: connect: connection refused [access_client]
```

I asked my network team if port 8046 is blocked somewhere, but they tell me it isn't. Nobody has logged into this server for about 10 days so I don't think it is user-caused.

Anybody have an idea?

I tried modifying my system.yaml file with the IP of the server, and restarting the app, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The artifactory product runs on a micro-service architecture, you can read more [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/jfrog-artifactory-service).

The first error message comes from the Jfrog Router [jfrou] micro-service reporting it could not connect to the access micro-service.
The 2nd message comes from the Artifactory micro service [jfrt] saying the same.
The 3rd message comes from the Metadata micro-service [jfmd] saying it also could not connect to the access micro service.

At this point I would suggest you go to the access-service.log and see if it is reporting any major errors. It is also worth noting that sometimes the Artifactory micro-serivce can be at fault for Access not starting, so please also check the artifactory-service.log if you see nothing suspicious in the access one.

We want to find where the restart begins in the log for that service - often with the words

```
    [service name] service initialization started
```

and find the first errors that occur after this in the log to determine the root issue.

If you can't see anything obvious stop Artifactory. Make sure all services have stopped with

```
    ps aux | grep art
```

Kill any lingering processes. Check that nothing is still listening on Artifactory [reserved ports](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-system-requirements-and-platform-support), then try a fresh start of Artifactory.

If all this fails, consider reaching out to JFrog Support for more help.

Answer (score 0):

David, thanks for the tip. That got me looking at other errors in the log. This showed up AFTER the hearbeat checks.

```
An SQL data change is not permitted for a read-only connection, user or database.
```

Apparently the db.lk file was owned by root for about 2 months. I don't know why the crash came up now, but after removing the db.lk file and restarting artifactory, a new db.lk file was created that was owned by artifactory:artifactory.

All is good now.